# Encoding of AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to scan QR Code by using AVCaptureSession. In the delegate of AVCaptureMetadataOutput, I can get AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject named `qrCodeObject` and get the string by `[qrCodeObject stringValue]`. I guess that the image of QR Code is decoded in UTF8, but it is garbled text if string of QR code is other encoding, such as Big5.

I have tried:

```
NSData *data = [qrCodeObject.stringValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSStringEncoding encBig5 = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingBig5);
NSString *correctString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:encBig5];
NSLog(@"%@", correctString);
```

But it's still garbled string.

### Any idea? Thanks.

I tried:

```
NSStringEncoding encBig5 = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingBig5);
NSLog(@"%@ is ｧAｦn", qrCodeObject.stringValue);
NSLog(@"%@ is <efbda741 efbda66e efbdb26e efbdb0ef bdb7>", [qrCodeObject.stringValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"%@ is 嚚你嚚好嚚爽嚚堆蔆", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[qrCodeObject.stringValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] encoding:encBig5]);
NSLog(@"%@ is (null)", [qrCodeObject.stringValue dataUsingEncoding:encBig5]);
```

Comment: Which is garbled text in your code? qrCodeObject.stringValue or correctString?

Comment: Both are garbled string.

Comment: Can you provide the garbled string?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work, I can't find a solution.

Comment: I have used couple of apps to scan that image, they all lead to the same garbled text, it might be that the qrcode doesn't support this encoding? Have you used ZXing on the image?

Comment: It should can be solved if used ZXing. I just confuse why Apple doesn't provide a raw NSData property of AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.

Comment: I just tested with ZXing, same result. Are you sure you can use ZXing get the desired result?